# Calling await on an async function throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function :

```js
async function fileHash(filename, algorithm = 'md5') {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Algorithm depends on availability of OpenSSL on platform
    // Another algorithms: 'sha1', 'md5', 'sha256', 'sha512' ...
    let shasum = crypto.createHash(algorithm);
    try {
      let s = fs.ReadStream(filename)
      s.on('data', function (data) {
        shasum.update(data)
      })
      // making digest
      s.on('end', function () {
        const hash = shasum.digest('hex')
        return resolve(hash);
      })
    } catch (error) {
      return reject('calc fail');
    }
  });
}
```

But when I use : `await fileHash(path, 'sha512');` I git this error : `await is only valid in async function`

Even though the function is an `async` function.

Comment: no, await is only valid **in** an async function - `fileHash` is `async` (even though you don't need it to be, since you don't need to use await in it) ... it's where you use `await` that has to be **in** an async function

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `fileHash`, it's with its caller. This

```
function external() {
    const foo = await fileHash(...someArgs);
}
```

Won't work. This

```
async function external() {
    const foo = await fileHash(...someArgs);
}
```

will.

(OTOH, `fileHash` itself doesn't need to be async to be `await`ed. You can even `await 2 + 2`).

Comment: In fact the error has gone, but it does not solve my problem, I'm using this function inside a loop and since it's async, I don't get the value when the loop finishes executing, is there any other way to make the function synchronous? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use await only inside async function, make sure you call it inside other function, declared async. If you call it on top level you have to use .then().catch().

Also, as your function return Promise, you no need to explicitly mark it as async.

Answer (score 1):

A function declared with async always returns a promise. find below code

```
 async function foo() {

 return "Hello";

   }

 async function display() {

 var message = await foo();

  console.log(message);

  }

  display()
```